# Load different splash screens based on OS language using manifest.mf file

Tags: java, awt, splash-screen, executable-jar, manifest.mf

I have a Java desktop application running from a JAR file, using a MANIFEST.MF file as follows:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: myMainClass
SplashScreen-Image: splashImage_en.jpg

Is there a way to specify more than one splashscreens and load the correct one based on the client OS language? For example, I want to load splashImage_en.jpg if the app is run on an English OS and splashImage_fr.jpg if run on a French OS.

Answer (score 1):

The AWT based [`SplashScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) does not provide that functionality.

However it *does* offer [`createGraphics()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html#createGraphics%28%29) over which we can paint anything we want.  That would be the way to show the localized message.  Have the splash image with no text to begin with, then draw localized text to it at run-time.